# Prevent creating new activities from notification click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have an app that use IntentService to work in background even if it is closed.

There is a button that launches background process and notification appears. This notification will not disappear until user press another button that stops IntentService.

But here I got another issue. I launch an app for the first time. Then press button that initialize IntentService, notification appears. Right after that when app is still on screen I press notification and it looks like app creates its duplicate. I can click notification multiple times and many copies of app are created.

Just found some tips like adding flags to PendingIntent and insert some strings in manifest but nothing helped so far.

Maybe there's something I need to change in notification or pending intent?

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    createNotificationChannel()

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0, notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    )
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Foreground Service Kotlin Example")
        .setContentText("kylsha")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()

    startForeground(1, notification)

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
```

Here is how it looks like

[image]

I want notification to launch activity only when app is closed or minimized and not create multiple copies of it. is something should be done to `pendingIntent`?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation. You have to use UPDATE_CURRENT flat on pending intent for the activity. You will get a callback onNewIntent method in activity with the updated intent. I had faced a similar issue  and I specifically remeber using onNewIntent callback to get the new intent with UPDATE_CURRENT flag for pending intent.

Comment: @JudeOsbertK thanks, you were right. And apart from that I had to put some strings in Manifes's acrivity sectiont: `android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it's help you

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setTicker("Transferring data...");
        notification.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        notification.setContentTitle("Transferring data...");
        notification.setOngoing(true);
        notification.setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(1,notification.build());
```

you can "close" a notification manually with

```
nm.cancel(1);
```